# Migrate persistentstore to iCloud

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, icloud

with this code, I can migrate persitentstore (core data) to iCloud:

```
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [[persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores]objectAtIndex:0];
    if(![persistentStoreCoordinator migratePersistentStore:persistentStore toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData] options:options withType:NSSQLiteStoreType error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"errore migrate %@", error);
    }
```

But I want to migrate only if the Ubiquity Container of iCloud is empty and the persistent store there isn't.

Comment: You can check the ubiquity containers /CoreData subdirectory for the presence of a directory matching the NSPersistentStoreUbiqitousContentNamekey. If this already exists them some other device has already created the store and shared it in iCloud.  Take a look at this link for more details on core data and iCloud integration http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/

Comment: Thats not necessarily true. It only means that some device has created that directory but there's no guarantee they finished uploading their data to iCloud. Also, if the device that created the directory suddenly dies (or loses network connectivity) it will never finish.

Comment: Sure but its the first step in identifying that Core Data has already tried to create ubiquity content for that `NSPersistentStoreUbiqitousContentNameKey' regardless of how successful it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is identical to the problem described in:

[How to seed initial data to Core Data + iCloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005285/how-to-seed-initial-data-to-core-data-icloud/21006130#21006130)

You can't reliably detect the initial state of the container, and therefore have to allow for the possibility of duplicate records after your migration.